# What OS Type setting to use for dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, asus

I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux and I'm trying to set up dual boot on my machine with Windows 10 for deep learning. I'm at the step where I'm trying to disable secure boot. I have a ASUS machine. I'm a bit confused by the UEFI/BIOS terms and how that plays into Ubuntu.

I'm wondering what exactly it means to disable secure boot, and what UEFI/BIOS means in this context? In the UEFI advanced firmware settings, it gives me the option to change the OS type from Windows UEFI mode to "other OS." If I disable secure boot, do I need to change the OS type to "other OS?"

I was able to boot Unbuntu from a live USB without disabling secure boot, but every tutorial I've looked at has told me to disable secure boot. This is also confusing me!

Basically, I've extremely new to this, and even the terminology has been quite a roadblock for me. Any guidance is much appreciated. [image: this is what my machine looks like]

Comment: Booting from the USB doesn't require grub2, but booting up a "real" ubuntu installation on your hard disk does.  And I seem to recall that grub2 doesn't work with secureboot, or at least it didn't the last time I checked.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Answer (score 4):

In short: Use "Other OS" as the option. You are not really disabling it but rather telling it to let you boot OS like Linux distros that don't have their bootloaders signed

Secure Boot is more or less a feature, kind of directed at Windows distros which allows for a more secure boot process. Unfortunately, it operates with certain keys or signed bootloaders that are mostly provided or rather recognised by/from Windows systems. Since the linux community is not on a common ground about how to deal with the key requirements of Secure Boot, there is no consistent approach hence most tutorials just tell you to disable it. What secure boot does is, prevent OS which doesn't have their bootloaders signed from booting. Most linux distros don't have their bootloaders signed at Microsoft and therefore problems can arise when booting. The "Other OS" option allows secure boot to not enforce it's key requirements and boot other operating systems as well. Therefore, you are not really disabling Secure boot in a turning it off sense, but rather telling it to chill down and let other distros do their thing.

A more detailed description can be found here: https://www.howtogeek.com/116569/htg-explains-how-windows-8s-secure-boot-feature-works-what-it-means-for-linux/

and on many other websites